# Oracle query to put rows at odd number adjacent to even number

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need some help in formulating data in Oracle. I will give an example -

I have a Table Customer with Name column.

```
Customer
  Name
  Ashish
  Amit
  Sunny
  Bob.
```

I want to get output in the format where names at odd number are adjacent to names at even number; output would be

```
Customer
Name1     Name2
Ashish    Amit
Sunny     Bob
```

and so on...

I tried following query but it doesn't give me the required output.

```
select  name, 
  case Mod(rownum,2) 
    when 1  then  name
  end  col1,   
  case Mod(rownum,2) 
    when 0  then  name 
  end  col2
from Customer
```

Comment: What defines whether a row is an odd or an even number? Rows are not naturally ordered in a relational database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This ia basically a `PIVOT` of the data but Oracle10g does not have the pivot function so you will have to replicate it using an aggregate and a `CASE` statement. If you apply the  [`row_number() over()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#i86310) as well you can transform the data into the result that you want.

```
select 
  max(case when col = 1 then name end) Name1,
  max(case when col = 0 then name end) Name2
from
(
  select name,  mod(rownum, 2) col,
    row_number() over(partition by mod(rownum, 2) order by name) rn
  from customer
) 
group by rn
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/500a5/18)

Result:

```
|  NAME1 | NAME2 |
------------------
| Ashish |  Amit |
|  Sunny |   Bob |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to group rows 2 by 2, you could try this:

```
SELECT MAX(decode(rn/2, floor(rn/2), NAME)) name1, 
       MAX(decode(rn/2, floor(rn/2), '', NAME)) name2
  FROM (SELECT c.*, rownum-1 rn 
          FROM Customer)
GROUP BY floor(rn/2)
```

The rows are ordered arbitrarily in the subquery. You could use analytics ([`row_number() OVER (ORDER BY ...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions156.htm#i86310)) to get a meaningful order.