# Oracle select pivot query to put row adjacent to their counter part using generic column name

Tags: sql, oracle, select, pivot

I have a table which each entry has a counter pair

```
Customer
   Name                Value
   Bob                 3
   Bob                 4
   Sam                 0
   Sam                 1
   Joe                 9
```

I want the following result

```
Customer
   Name                Value1          Value2
   Bob                 3               4
   Sam                 0               1
   Joe                 9
```

I have read this thread, [Oracle query to put rows at odd number adjacent to even number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837026/oracle-query-to-put-rows-at-odd-number-adjacent-to-even-number), but I want to avoid using the MOD function instead possible using pivot instead.

Comment: Is it possible to have three or move value for Bob?

Comment: no, each name will have no more than 2

Comment: And how will you work with endless report? Do you expect XML or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the pivot statement here, if you have only two value for each name (it also works with dates, because we can use max and min for dates):

```
select name, min(value) value1, nullif(max(value), min(value)) value2
  from customer_tables
 group by name
```

If Bob, Sam and other have more that two value:

```
with t (Name, Value) as (
select 'Bob',3 from dual union all
select 'Bob',4 from dual union all
select 'Sam',0 from dual union all
select 'Sam',1 from dual union all
select 'Joe',9 from dual 
), t1 (name, value, rn) as (
select name, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by name order by value) from t
)
select * from t1
pivot XML (
  max(value) 
  for rn in (ANY)
)

SQL> l
  1  with t (Name, Value) as (
  2  select 'Bob',3 from dual union all
  3  select 'Bob',4 from dual union all
  4  select 'Sam',0 from dual union all
  5  select 'Sam',1 from dual union all
  6  select 'Joe',9 from dual
  7  ), t1 (name, value, rn) as (
  8  select name, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by name order by value) from t
  9  )
 10  select * from t1
 11  pivot XML (
 12    max(value)
 13    for rn in (ANY)
 14* )
SQL> /

NAM RN_XML
--- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Bob <PivotSet><item><column name = "RN">1</column><column name = "MAX(VALUE)">3</col
    umn></item><item><column name = "RN">2</column><column name = "MAX(VALUE)">4</co
    lumn></item></PivotSet>

Joe <PivotSet><item><column name = "RN">1</column><column name = "MAX(VALUE)">9</col
    umn></item></PivotSet>

Sam <PivotSet><item><column name = "RN">1</column><column name = "MAX(VALUE)">0</col
    umn></item><item><column name = "RN">2</column><column name = "MAX(VALUE)">1</co
    lumn></item></PivotSet>
```

Read more about pivot [here](http://diefororacle.blogspot.ru/2014/08/pivot-sql-extenssion-for-oracle-database.html)

Comment: interesting. what if the value is a date? How do you get around this?

Comment: hold on, I wrote the query with endless number of record for Bob, Sam and other